# How do I verify user through zerodev?

Tags: node.js, decentralized-applications, web3auth

I have integrated Zero Dev and web3auth sdk in my system.
Now I want to verify users in the backend. So I tried to send web3auth.user.idtoken in the backend that verifies users but the wallet address it returns different from the one that I get in front end through zerodev signer. So I am inferring that zerodev's assigned address and web3auth assigned address are not same. So how do I now verify my user in the backend and recive the same address that zerodev provides.

I expecting to verify and register the users in backend.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It was a theoretical question. Where will I get any code?

Answer (score 0):

zeroDev creates a new wallet, and it is unique so those 2 address would be seperate. By verify if you mean you want to check if the signature is correct and validate it then I suggest you use a nonce to sign it and then verify by decoding/verifying the nonce

*nonce is just a fancy name for a unique_id/value